# How to use Bat file excute dbms_stats for oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to excute a batch file to excute command like "exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname=>'xxx',degree => 8,cascade =>true)",

First,I have writed file xx.sql and use sqlplus to run,but it no working.

Second,I have writed batch file directly like "sqlplus xxx/xxx@xx dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname=>'xxx',degree => 8,cascade =>true)" still not run.

Please help me how to excute this sql.Thk~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

**xx.sql**:

> ```
> begin
> dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname=>'tejash',degree => 8,cascade =>true);
> end;
> /
> exit;
> ```

**mybat.bat**:

> ```
> @echo off 
> sqlplus sys/oracle as sysdba @xx.sql
> Echo Stats gathered successfully. 
> echo Press any key to exit the script..
> PAUSE >nul
> ```

Now, execute it by double clicking on **mybat.bat** file and you will find the following output:

> ```
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Dec 4 10:24:57 2019
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
>
> Connected to:
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
>
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
> Stats gathered successfully.
> Press any key to exit the script..
> ```

Cheers!!